# Hardcode OTP in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, one-time-password, identity-experience-framework

We are using PhoneFactor Technical profile to validate a phone number during registration process. Our performance testing team is going to test the flows hence for automation they are looking forward for hardcoded OTPs. Is it in any way achievable by Azure AD B2C(to ardcode the OTP)?

Comment: You can't Hardcode the OTP for PhoneFactor Technical profile to validate a phone number which is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Moving from comments to answer)

OTP's Can't be hardcoded for PhoneFactor Technical profile to validate a phone number.